# Constraints about

Tags: constraints

What constraints are copied with table when we create table by using create table as select statement..?

Comment: Mysql and oracle are two different products with different answers to this question. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about MySQL, but - as of Oracle - only the NOT NULL constraint. Even if there was a column designed as a primary key (which - implicitly - means that it can't be NULL), newly created table won't have that constraint.

For example:

```
SQL> create table test_1
  2    (id     number primary key,
  3     name   varchar2(20) not null);

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name, constraint_Type from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST_1';

CONSTRAINT_NAME      C
-------------------- -
SYS_C009194          C     --> "C"heck (NOT NULL) constraint
SYS_C009195          P     --> "P"rimary key constraint

SQL> create table test_2 as select * from test_1;

Table created.

SQL> select constraint_name, constraint_Type from user_constraints where table_name = 'TEST_2';

CONSTRAINT_NAME      C
-------------------- -
SYS_C009196          C       --> that's the "C"heck - NOT NULL constraint

SQL> desc test_2
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 NAME                                      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL would only preserve NOT NULL as constarint

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY)
```

```
create table tab2
      (id     int primary key,
       col1   varchar(20) not null,
  col2 int UNIQUE,
  col3 int,   FOREIGN KEY (col3) REFERENCES tab1(id))
```

```
CREATE TABLE tab3 AS SELECT * FROM tab2
```

> ```
> Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE tab3
```

| Table | Create Table |
| --- | --- |
| tab3 | CREATE TABLE `tab3` ( `id` int NOT NULL, `col1` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `col2` int DEFAULT NULL, `col3` int DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IiTq4KvR)